# Pointer deck of cards replace function C++

Tags: c++, pointers, replace, linked-list, singly-linked-list

What I have to do is this:

Add a function replace to the deck class that is passed a card as a parameter by value. The
card is placed on the bottom of the deck

CardPtr is a private class variable, it is set to the top card of the deck in the constructor

```
node<card> *newCard; //card pointer
newCard = new node<card>(card(2, 0), NULL);  //points to the first card
CardPtr = newCard; //sets cardpointer to newcard
```

A separate class takes the top card off and diplays the value, deleting that node from the deck in the process.  I am trying to put that card back in on the bottom.  then this is the code:

```
    `void deck::replace(card BottomCard)
    {
        int count = 0;
        node<card> *replaceptr;
        bottom = NULL;
        replaceptr = new node<card>(BottomCard, NULL);
        if (bottom != NULL)
        {
    bottom->next = replaceptr;
        }
        else
        {
    bottom = replaceptr;
        }

        if (count >= 52)
        {
            throw overflowError("ERROR: Deck is already full");
        }

        //CardPtr = new node<card>(BottomCard, NULL);
        //bottom->next = CardPtr;
}
```

I implement it in my main code and it seems to replace the card at the top of the deck.  Can anyone help me please? Thank you.

Here is the Constructor I have in full:

```
    deck::deck() // deck constructor
{
    node<card> *newCard; //card pointer
    newCard = new node<card>(card(2, 0), NULL);  //points to the first card
    CardPtr = newCard; //sets cardpointer to newcard

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 2; j < 15; j++)
        {
            if (i == 0 && j == 2) continue;

            node<card> *temp = new node<card>(card(j, i), NULL);  // temporary pointer sets card value and suit to numbers for value and suit

            newCard->next = temp;// sets newcard pointer .next to temp
            newCard = temp;// sets newcard to temp          
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post a minimal compilable test case. At least include class definition with attributes (I suppose `CardPtr` is a class attribute).

Comment: You have other issues with the code you posted.  The one glaring error is that you allocate memory for "bottom", and then replace the value of "bottom" in your while loop.  Therefore you have a memory leak.

Comment: What is the initial value of `CardPtr`?  That's not clear from the code given, and may be critical to your logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's the responsibility of `CardPtr` to always point at the top card (the start of the linked list), then this method's code should be changed so that it **does not modify** `CardPtr`.  Perhaps declare another local variable, initialize it to equal `CardPtr` and then modify *that* pointer repeatedly in your loop (so that `CardPtr` never changes).

It's also possible that your other method that deals a card from the top of the deck is not leaving `CardPtr` in a good state (pointing at the new top card), which means you've got more than one problem to fix.

Comment: CardPtr works in the other methods to point to the right card every time, so I will try creating a new pointer.

Comment: Trouble-shooting tip: Create another method that retrieves the bottom node in the deck.  You can use that method within this one to find the bottom node, and you can also call it after other method calls (like the one that deals cards) to verify that everything is where it should be.

Comment: I've edited my code, It's back to exiting after 52 cards.  I assume I need to edit my constructor?

Comment: got it! wish i could give you all an answer because the combination helped me out... what I ultimately needed to do was not change cardptr though so thank you very much

Comment: Glad to hear it!  (Remember: Don't lose the head of that list, or you'll never get it back!)  :-)

Answer (score 1):

You need to determine the *second-to-last* node in the list (the card before the bottom card), because that node's `next` pointer will need to refer to the new bottom card.

Then, simply change the `next` entry of the second-to-last node to the new node.

[image]

(Be sure to delete the old bottom card node after you insert the new one, or else you may end up with a memory leak)

**EDIT**

If you were to use a circular list, you could save the effort of scanning the list for the last node. You could store a pointer to the last node, whose `next` pointer (instead of being null) would refer to the first node.

Comment: Thanks, I have a separate function which deals the top card, and I pass that card in so that is like taking the top card and putting it on the bottom using this function...  But I cant seem to get this logic down, how exactly would I look for the 2nd to last?

Comment: Look at the graphic I added. You can tell whether a node contains the card before the last by checking if its next node's `next` entry is null.

Comment: Perhaps @Tony the Pony has misinterpreted the goal, which is not entirely clear to me either.  It seems you're not trying to "replace" a card that's already in the deck (take it out and put in the one given), but rather "place" the given card at the bottom of the deck.  Am I right?

Comment: Just declare two pointers, one pointer being "one" ahead of the other.   Advance each pointer until the one that is ahead reaches the end.  Then you know the other pointer is behind it, i.e. second from the end.

Comment: Just to be clear, is the replacement card already in the deck? If so, you will also need to unlink its node from the list, or else you will wind up with a screwed up list.

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm not clear.  There is another function that deals the card off the top and it gets deleted from the deck, I then display the value (ex. Ace of Spades), and then that card is put in the bottom of the deck.  I'm trying to pass that card to be put on the bottom, so basically once it gets to this function it is one card being put into a deck of 51 cards

Answer (score 1):

Look here

```
bottom = new node <card>;

while (CardPtr != NULL)
{
    if (CardPtr->next == NULL)
    {
        bottom = CardPtr;
    }
}
```

First, you allocate a new card and assign it to `bottom`, then in your `while` loop you assign `bottom` to `CardPtr` which will cause a memory leak. you should instead remove the *new* and just set `bottom` to `NULL`.

```
CardPtr = new node<card>(BottomCard, NULL);
if ( bottom != NULL )
{
  bottom->next = CardPtr;
}
else
{
  bottom = CardPtr;
}
```

Comment: When I implement this it still just prints out the same card over and over, I know it must be the replace function because without it, it goes through 52 times until the deck is empty